# Why does this ligand form 6-coordinate complexes with Transition elements and 8-coordinate complexes with Inner transition elements?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, coordination-compounds, transition-metals, valence-bond-theory, ligand-field-theory

[image]

The ligand given above shows different denticities with common transition and inner-transition metal ion i.e. 6 and 8.

The extra two denticities come from the two Nitrogen having 1 lone pair each. I want to know why is inner-transition metal ion able to somehow get nitrogen to donate these lone pairs while a common transition ion fails to do so?

Answer (score 3):

I decided to do some more research for this question as I had faced it before. Turns out the proper name of this ligand is **[diethylenetriaminepentaacetate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pentetic_acid) ($\ce{DTPA^5-}$)**. It's an expanded version of EDTA and is primarily used in MRI scanning where it forms complexes with the Gadolinium ion. It forms complexes with a coordination number of six and seven with transition metals simply because these complexes are more stable. Here's Fe(III)-DTPA as an example<sup>1</sup>:

> Experimentally Fe(III)-DTPA has been observed to adopt seven- and six-coordinate
> crystal structures. This agrees with our result where the 8-coordinate Fe(III)-DTPA is $\pu{23 kJ mol^-1}$ higher in energy relative to the most stable 7-coordinate structure
>
> [image]

With inner transition metals, it forms complexes with a denticity of 8, with Pr-DTPA being an example<sup>2</sup>:
[image]

**References:**

1. Sillanpää, Atte J., et al. “Density Functional Complexation Study of Metal Ions with (Amino) Polycarboxylic Acid Ligands.” Phys. Chem. Chem. Phys., vol. 5, no. 16, **2003**, *pp. 3382–93*. doi:[10.1039/B303234P](https://doi.org/10.1039/B303234P).
2. Fusaro, Luca, et al. “Insight into the Dynamics of Lanthanide-DTPA Complexes As Revealed by Oxygen-17 NMR.” Inorganic Chemistry, vol. 51, no. 15, **2012**, *pp. 8455–61*. doi:[10.1021/ic3010085](https://doi.org/10.1021/ic3010085).

Comment: So it is based on factual data or is there a way to see the structure of ligand and then decide?

Comment: inner transition metals prefer to form complexes with high CN as they have open f-orbitals. this ligand has 8 sites which can donate electron pairs, and it will prefer to coordinate with all those sites when it can. That's how I initially went about solving this problem without knowing the fact.

Comment: Okay. Can't transition metals show CN 8 with this ligand?

Comment: They can, but those compounds are unstable, as I mentioned in my answer